# How can I poll an ajax request in astro

Tags: server-side-rendering, astrojs, swr, ajax-polling

Is there some way I can poll to an endpoint using astro??

I'm currently using SSR to get the data from the endpoint at page request time. But I would like to poll to that endpoint and update the astro component every few seconds. How would I achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

## Solution SSE

you can achieve that with SSE Server Sent Event.
in this example I update Astro client side from events coming from mqtt client running on the server, so that client can see updates coming without refreshing the page nor keep polling an api.

## Example

### api

```js
import {logger} from '@/libs/logger.js'
import {SSE_Emitter} from '@/libs/heat_state'

export async function get({request}){

    logger.info("heat_events> get()")
    
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        start(controller){
            const events_listener = (devices)=>{
                if(controller){
                    logger.verbose("heat_events> SSE_Emitter 'heat'")
                    const data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(devices)}\r\n\r\n`;
                    controller.enqueue(data)
                }else{
                    logger.warn("heat_events> no sse_controller")
                }
            }
            SSE_Emitter.off('heat',events_listener)
            SSE_Emitter.on('heat',events_listener)
        },
        cancel(){
            logger.info("heat_events> cancel() closing")
            if(sse_controller){
                sse_controller.close()
            }
        }
    })

    return new Response(stream, {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'          
        }
    });
}
```

### client script

```js
function setup_sse(){
        const evtSource = new EventSource("/api/heat_events")
    
        evtSource.onmessage = (event) => {
            dispatch_heat_state(JSON.parse(event.data))
        }
        evtSource.onerror = (err) => {
              console.error("EventSource failed:", err);
              evtSource.close();
        };  
    }
    setup_sse()
```

## Reference example

as it is more practicale to see the above code in real example, here reference in a full project with the above code

- api ReadableStream
  https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-home-control/blob/d81c4cd37bee4466428c75bc2c1d406b61a9db5f/src/pages/api/heat_events.js#L8
- client event source https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-home-control/blob/d81c4cd37bee4466428c75bc2c1d406b61a9db5f/src/pages/index.astro#L59

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong..for this the server has to trigger an event in response to some action right?? 

In my case I have no such action that can trigger an event. I just want to poll to a GET request of an external API

Comment: you are right, polling is easy, but I would not recommend it, because the client is consumer and does not know if the data changed or not, while the server as producer knows exactly when the data change and can minimize traffic by sending update only on change.

Comment: Yess I get that, But it's an external API(lastfm -to get the current/recent played tracks), I don't have any control neither do I know when the data updates. 

Is there any better way to manage this?

Comment: you're right, if you did not design the API then my solution is not applicable, so even if it does not count as answer for your problem, I guess it could help people coming here because your question did not specify that particularity. Now to help your problem, I don't see why you wouldn't use a vanilla js script for that (in Astro script tag).